# HTML Responsiveness not working

Tags: html, css

I'm facing issue for responsiveness using DreamWeaver 2017.

The CSS for the logo :

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 6cm;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /*width: 139px;*/
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);

}
```

[image: Site header]

Upon trying out the responsiveness :

[image]

I'm aware i'm using margin left which caused it.

The objective is to adapt both site and mobile site like this :

[image]

Also, if you observed even the input box also indent to the right..

```
.menu2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left: 1.2cm;
    color: #000000;
    height: 40px; 
}
```

I'm looking on other method than padding or margin.
Any critic/suggestion is welcome.

HTML codes:

```
 <header> 
<!-- This is the header content. It contains Logo and links -->
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="sojologo"/> 
    <font color="black" class="menu1">ABOUT</font>
    <button id="logodropdown"><img src="dropdown_arrow.png"/></button>
    <a href="#" class="menu2">SIGN IN/<br>REGISTER</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu2">PROMOTIONS</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu2">TRAVEL</a><button id="logodropdown"><img src="dropdown_arrow.png"/></button>

<div class="menu2" style="border: 3px solid #DDD;">
    <img  src="icon_search.png"/>
       <input size="50%"  placeholder="Quick Search for any city or 
              street in Japan" style="border:none;"/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
```

Codepenio : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/xrxbZz

Comment: Got any HTML for us to check out?

Comment: @trav, adding it in a jiffy.

Comment: @trav, i've just added

Comment: I've never seen anyone use centimeters in CSS before.  That's a first.

Comment: btw you don't have to close img tag

Comment: Pretty cool huh @JosephMarikle, I recently discovered this myself.  Hell you can do inches, millimeters and now even fractions with the new "fr" unit.

Comment: can  u make a codepen or somethin where we can see it?

Comment: @YahyaEssam, thanks for pointing that out. Almost forgot about it.

Comment: @Jnui, i've just added the link below

Comment: One thing that I've noticed right off the bat is that you've given several elements the ID of "menu2".  To give something an ID is very specific and should only apply to one element, use class for multiple elements.  
edit:  Also using <font> which is deprecated with HTML5.

Comment: @trav, thanks for the heads up. really appreciate that note and advice.

Comment: Your margin is not responsive.

Comment: @Daniel, yeap. I kinda realize that. Should i put in multiple id and align it to left?

Comment: You should just use a class likely and use media queries. Find some on youtube or blogs. You should really learn that stuff and some time investment will solve your issue here.

Comment: @Daniel, really like that suggestion. It's my first time hearing media query. I'm going to check on it now .

Comment: Really? You just sayed media queries weren't working ._.

Comment: @RompePC, looks like it's not working. Someone just posted an answer. I'm going to post the output. a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here that we can look at. One thing others have commented on is that your HTML needs cleaned up. Make sure that IDs are truly unique, and that each opening tag has a closing tag (except for self-contained elements, like images and inputs).

You could also stand to use some wrapping elements to help you contain the main areas of your header: the logo, the nav items, and the search.

From there, to help with responsiveness, I would recommend using percentages for your widths whenever possible, instead of absolute units like centimeters. This will help your display flex a little bit at bigger screen sizes. At some point, though, you'll need to just redo the layout because the screen will be too wide to fit all your elements in one line. That's where [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) come into play.

Media queries will let you override a base style when the screen is smaller (or larger) than a certain width. For example, we could set the body to be blue normally, then change to red on smaller screens:

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Another thing we can do to tidy things up and make our life easier is to use classes when possible. The nav items are a good use case for this: most of their styles will be shared. We can give them each an ID just in case, but we may not even need to use all those IDs.

**Edit:** Another tidying opportunity I meant to mention is that the use of the [`<font>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) tag is deprecated as of HTML5, so you should avoid that in your HTML. I removed it from the HTML in my snippet below. (End edit.)

A final thing you can do is make the little triangles next to the nav items [with HTML and CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) instead of as images. (You could also do these purely in CSS using pseudo elements.)

Here is a demo where I've cleaned up your HTML quite a bit and then heavily revised the CSS to look more like what's in the pictures you provided. I have used placeholder images with my best guess at their real sizes based on the picture. You'll see that as you resize the screen, the media queries kick in to make the header get taller and to center things in the middle of the screen.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */
a:hover {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
  background-color: #73A7D1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#header-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#logo, nav, #search {
  float: left;
}
#logo {
  width: 110px;
  height: 50px;
}
nav {
  width: 60%;
}
#search {
  width: 200px;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  max-width: 100px; /* forces "sign in/register to break at <wbr> tab */
  text-align: center;
}
#menu2 {
  position: relative; /* bump "sign in/register" down a bit */
  top: 7px;
}
.triangle-down { /* dropdown arrows next to nav links */
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
#search img, #search input {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}
#search img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#search input {
  width: 150px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  header {
    height: 160px;
  }
  #logo, nav, #search {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 550px) {
  header {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/110x50" alt="sojologo"></div>
    <nav>
      <div class="menu-item" id="menu1">ABOUT<span class="triangle-down"></span></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="menu2"><a href="#">SIGN IN/<wbr>REGISTER</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="menu3"><a href="#">PROMOTIONS</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="menu4"><a href="#">TRAVEL<span class="triangle-down"></span></a></div>
    </nav>

    <div id="search">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"/>
      <input placeholder="Quick Search for any city or street in Japan" />
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This content seriously has a lot of useful educational nformation. My upvote is with you . A second, i want to try it out !

Comment: You're a genius ! I learn something new today : http://imgur.com/a/nxtmy
. A quick question , separating the height and width is advisable or mixing it? for the media query.

Comment: Separating how and in regards to which element(s)?

Comment: Well, i saw online there was code like these:
`@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}`

Comment: Ah. Well that would simply depend on your specific case. If you want the rule to apply when the width *and* height cross a certain threshold, you would put them in the same rule, and the rule would only apply if both conditions were met. If you do separate queries for width and height, the rules from each query would apply if that particular query was met – potentially either, both, or neither applying at any given time.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice and I gain new knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

well FreedomPride
you can specify different properties for every class in each size of screens
you can use media query in this situation.
for example :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
       .menu2 {
        margin-left:20px;
        }
     }
```

as you see here I changed the margin in small screens 480px wide to 20px
and you can use it for each size

320px

480px

720px

1200px

you may get more information for mediaquery from here :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

here's example of how we can do it :

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */
a:hover {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
/*header*/
header {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 font-size: 16px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#menu1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}
.menu2 {
    display: inline-flex;
 text-decoration:none;
    margin-left: 1.2cm;
 color: #000000;
    height: 40px; 
}
/* Logo placeholder*/
#logo {
 margin-left: 6cm;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 /*width: 139px;*/
 text-align: left;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
 
}
#logodropdown {
 margin-left: 0px; 
 border: none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
/* div for Links in header */
#headerLinks {
 float: left;
 width: calc( 100% - 139px );
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
/* Links in header */

#imgContainer{
    float:left;
}
#headerLinks a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 padding-left: 66px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
/* Offer text banner*/
#offer {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 clear: both;
 background-color: rgba(246,246,246,1.00);
 color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
 padding-top: 57px;
 padding-bottom: 57px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  #logo {
 margin-left: 1cm;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 /*width: 139px;*/
 text-align: left;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
 
}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  #logo {
 margin-left: 1cm;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 /*width: 139px;*/
 text-align: left;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
 
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
      #logo {
        margin-left:30px;
      }
      #menu1 {
        margin-left:35px;
      }
      .menu2 {
        margin-left:20px;
      }
      .menu2 input {
        max-width:300px;
      }
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      #logo {
        margin-left:25px;
      }
      #menu1 {
        margin-left:25px;
        font-size:18px;
      }
      .menu2 {
        margin-left:15px;
        font-size:14px;
      }
      .menu2 input {
        max-width:250px;
        font-size:11px;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
      #logo {
        margin-left:10px;
      }
      #menu1 {
        margin-left:10px;
        font-size:13px;
      }
      .menu2 {
        margin-left:5px;
        font-size:10px;
      }
      .menu2 input {
        max-width:150px;
        font-size:10px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<header> 
<!-- This is the header content. It contains Logo and links -->
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="sojologo"> 
  <font color="black" id="menu1">ABOUT</font>
  <button id="logodropdown"><img src="dropdown_arrow.png"></button>
  <a href="#" class="menu2">SIGN IN/<br>REGISTER</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu2">PROMOTIONS</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu2">TRAVEL</a><button id="logodropdown"><img src="dropdown_arrow.png"></button>


<div class="menu2" style="border: 3px solid #DDD;">
    <img  src="icon_search.png"/>
    <input size="50%"  placeholder="   Quick Search for any city or street in Japan" style="border: none;"/>
</div>
```

**Notice:** This isn't the best practice. but for more efficient you have to use any grid system or framework like bootstrap, foundation or uikit.

Comment: got it, really appreciate your time, this information would be useful for others. So i'm going to upvote all the helpful decisions.

Comment: example added. sure it's just example you may to use the same way to show the best view you will like on each screen size. regards

Answer (score 0):

First, on the Codepen, the header and the logo div tag is not closed (no end tags), if you start fixing that, it fix a lot. Second, it is a bit confusing naming, you have the logo div tag surrounding the  menu items. Try to have more logic structure at first, and add a wrapper, like:

```
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="menu1">LINKS</div>
 <div class="menu2">INPUT</div>
 </div> 
</header>
```

Also try to put images tags in div tags, as they may live their own life, if not.

Then try to use more modern CSS, like flexbox (you actually have one inline-flex). In this flex you tell it to wrap the menu1 and menu2 to difference rows, if they do not fit width in browser window. So on the wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1200px;
}
```

You can actually use flexbox on menu1 and menu2 also, then you can tell links to not wrap. You also need to set the flex directive correlating to the surrounding wrapper,  **flex: 1 1 NUMBER**:

```
.menu1 {
flex: 1 1 65%;
display: flex;
justify-content: end;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
width: 65%;
}
.menu2 {
 flex: 1 1 35%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: start;
width: 35%;
}
```

For the record, you may need to set width to something lower than 65 and 35, if you have margins and paddings on them.

Last, I would set the input box width only within  CSS, so that it will shrink in some resolutions, by setting a max-width, like:

```
.menu2 input { display: inline-block; max- width: 200px; }
```

After that you can set media queries on the resolutions you need, for an example change width on menu1 and menu2 to 100%, both. You may also need to adjust max-width on input.

Good luck!
Klas

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check for [media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to get full responsiveness in any width/height you want.

Comment: There's no effect , it doesn't fix my issue. You could try it yourself in the codepen.io .

Comment: While OP probably does need media queries, this isn't really an answer to the question. An example of the specific media queries he could use would be better.

Comment: why are people downvoting your post -.-, i mean it's helpful to me.